# How to set additional variables upon form submit, based on value of one of the submitted fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form and upon `create` I would like it to save additional variables not included in the form itself. Therefore in my create method I have a line `params[:invitation][:person_two_id] = @person_two.id` (See below). By calling this line before `.save` I thought this would include the `person_two_id` when saving the invitation. However, this is not the case. The debugger (see code below where I placed the debugger) shows:

- `params[:invitation][:person_two_id]` is `101`
- `@invitation` has `nil` as value for `person_two_id`: `#<Invitation id: 171, person_one_id: nil, person_two_id: nil, organization_id: 87, email: "example@example.com", message: "dsfsd", created_at: "2015-07-07 14:36:35", updated_at: "2015-07-07 14:36:35">`

Hence, when saving @invitation, is has not automatically also saved the `person_two_id` value for @invitation. Why not? What should I do differently?

My controller method:

```
def create
  @invitation = Invitation.new(new_params)
  @person_two = User.find_by(email: params[:invitation][:email].downcase)
  params[:invitation][:person_two_id] = @person_two.id
  @invitation.save
  debugger
  InvitationMailer.invitation(@invitation).deliver_now
end
```

Comment: tried using `save!` instead of `save`?

Comment: You could include a hidden field in your form and auto-populate it with the necessary params.

Comment: Tried `save!` but that makes no difference. I don't think a hidden field would be the way to go. For one reason, the value for the field can only be determined after submitting the form since its value depends on values entered in the form. But also, it's the principle that I'm looking for: how to add additional variables/parameters, through the controller (instead of by filling in the values in the form), that are included when subsequently calling `save`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to replace `params[:invitation][:person_two_id] = @person_two.id` with `@invitation.person_two_id = @person_two.id` and it worked.